# Solar tracker location with Plex-Earth and Virto.CAD

Tags: cad, solar-radiation

I need to use Plex-Earth and Virto.CAD to solve a solar panel positioning problem.
I am on BricsCAD.

I have a KML for a boundary area.

How can I, using this software, get the following ground mount build:
Trackers will have to be installed on the ground, only in locations with a maximum inclination of 10 degrees to the south and -5 degrees to the north. Trackers 7 metres apart.

With Plex-Earth slope and direction I am having trouble understanding what maximum inclination 10º south and -5 degrees north mean.